# Python web scraping on https and a dialog box login

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, https, dialog

Hi recently taken project to develop a mobile site and decided to use web scraping to use data from a college site, but I have ran into a problem.

Information on server:
It's running asp.net works with all user agents and when you goto www.example.com/login/ it brings up a login dialog box.

I'm using python to write this app because cross platform anyways I have tried using urlib techniques and I get 401 unauthorised even when I have add password and user name I will post code when i get home.

I got a mechanizm browser setup with a cookie jar, but still no luck giving me 401, 
https://studentportal.burycollege.ac.uk/homeportal/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/, is a hight level abstraction for the urllib and urllib2 modules, is very easy to use. I use in my projects.